# Can you use maps from Crazy bump in the BGE

Tags: texturing, game-engine

I have been wanting to increase the quality of my textures in the blender game engine and was wondering if the different maps that are created on the program CrazyBump could be used in the BGE on textures to make them look better.  Sorry if this question seems obvious or whatnot as I am new to blender, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Blender does not care what tools you use to create images. You can even draw it with pencils on a canvas.

Blender cares the image format such as jpg, png, dds, tga.

However you created your images, turn them into one of the supported formats and you can use them within Blender and the BGE.

Comment: Yes I understand that however the nodes i used to use the images i different maps i created in the other program dont exist when i switch to the blender game engine.  Idk if there is some other way to input maps like normal, displacement, specularity, and occlusion?